# Hosting MS SQL Express Edition Online

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to host MS SQL Express to be use as reporting source online
and What are the required things for the setup?

Comment: What do you mean by online? Do you mean in the cloud/internet? If so I suggest you get a free subscription to Azure and create a SQL Server and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365166(v=sql.105).aspx):

> **How Reporting Services Works with SQL Server Express The following**
>
> list describes how Reporting Services works in SQL Server Express:
>
> - All the server components of both SQL Server Express and Reporting
>     Services are installed on a single server. You cannot store the report
>     server database on a remote server. All data sources that provide data
>     to reports must connect to SQL Server relational databases are that
>     are installed on the local instance of SQL Server.
> - All reports are processed on demand. Scheduled or unattended report processing is not supported.
> - SQL Server Express always installs a named instance of the
>     SQL Server database engine. Therefore data source connection strings
>     and Reporting Services URLs must include the instance name.